# MySQL Workbench HTTP tunnel

Tags: http, tunneling, mysql

Is there way in MySQL Workbench to connect to a database via HTTP Tunnel?

I've used HTTP tunnel for a while with Navicat and I would like to connect on same way to a remote databases with MySQL Workbench.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navicat probably uses a PHP script hosted on a web server to work via an HTTP tunnel, if it works like similar products. MySQL Workbench doesn't have that feature as far as I know. You'd have to tunnel via SSH as Steve Mayne suggests.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to set up a tunnel to do this.  Once you've established your connection, simply connect your MySQL Workbench to the local port that you've tunnelled to your remote server.

Obviously you'll need to be running to appropriate tunnel server on the remote-side to be able to accept your connection and establish the real TCP connection with the MySQL server.